# How to linearize a conditional constraint in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

How can I linearize this constraint:

- if $x\leq 0 $ then $y=0$
- if $x > 0$ then $y=1$

Comment: What types of variables are $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suppose $x$ is not an Integer:**

Let $M$ denote the “largest” number in $\Bbb R$, and then let $y$ be a binary variable and do the following:

$$x\le yM$$
$$x>-M(1-y)$$

That strict inequality, $>$, is going to make the feasible region open. So, depending on the objective function of the original problem, this could mean the model is infeasible.

**Suppose $x$ is an Integer:**

Let $M$ denote the “largest” number in $\Bbb R$, and then let $y$ be a binary variable and do the following:

$$x\le yM$$
$$x\ge -M(1-y)+1$$